# Wagtail not shows ValidationError correctly

Tags: django, validation, wagtail

I have XOR validation of `wagtail.core.models.Page` descedant:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.video_playlist is not None and self.gallery is not None:
        raise ValidationError(_("Only gallery or only video playlist must be filled"))
    elif self.video_playlist is None and self.gallery is None:
        raise ValidationError(_("Only gallery or only video playlist must be filled"))
    super(OkoPage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But instead of red color highlighting wagtail returns 400 error.[image]
How to do it right?

Comment: You probably want to make each error message unique so you know which one you're looking at.

Comment: It's not the question about that. I need to handle `ValidationError` in wagtail's page form as django's admin do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should perform this validation in a `clean` method on the model, not within `save`. This way, the `ValidationError` will be caught by Django's form handling logic and converted into an error message on the form.

The `save` method is only called after the form handling has been completed, so throwing a `ValidationError` at that point is too late for it to be handled nicely.